# Wriiting Numbers in Reference to Guns and Ammunition

Tags: numbers

In reference to ammunition and guns, when the word "caliber" is used after a number, 380, for example, should the decimal that's typically present be omitted?  I lean towards "no" because caliber is a measurement reference, but it doesn't change the measurement.  Any hard and fast rules in re writing about measurements for ammunition and guns in general would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest that you ask the question on a firearms forum.

Comment: Or read documentation and sales/advertising material. There's a ton of stuff written about guns: military history, true crime, instructional texts...

Comment: @HotLicks: I was under the impression that questions were to be a) meaningful and, b) posed in the title. For instance: "Is this right?" does not qualify. Was I wrong?

Comment: @Ricky -- The question is reasonably meaningful, and the title covers it reasonably well.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question to ask of English speaking group/forum. We all might learn something.

Comment: @HotLicks: Oh? There isn't even a question mark in the title.

Comment: At the level of general English usage, this is surely open to opinion. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22) / [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.22_caliber) uses both forms. As does [Military Today](http://www.military-today.com/life/what_are_all_the_different_22_calibers_22_rifle_vs_22_pistol.htm). // A stipulative definition belongs, I believe, on a dedicated forum, but will not exactly reflect general usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That Military Today page seems to be consistent in using the decimal point.

Comment: Small-arms calibers are cited either in metric (_9mm_) or fractional inches (_.38_). The _mm_ or the fractional decimal point are required in writing in ordinary situations,, but in speech neither is necessary.

Comment: @Barmar Not in the title.

Comment: @Barmar [Ammo.com](https://ammo.com/rimfire/22-lr-ammo) seems to use the two terms interchangeably, at least at the start of this sales page, though it soon settles down to one choice. Perhaps some trade names _must_ include / exclude the decimal point.

Comment: Different groups of shooters, as military, police, club shooters have different rules in different jurisdictions. Here in the UK, one of the best-known sources is Janes Information Services, particularly Jane's Directory of Military Small Arms Ammunition.